# Styling individual features in a GeoJSON layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson, css

I have managed to display a GeoJSON layer with multiple polygons (~150) in a Leaflet map in SharePoint.

I would like to style different features in this GeoJSON layer according to  a colour stored within a column in this GeoJSON layer, called "color". 
So far the output is only diplaying by default: "blue"

```
// Polygons coloured
      $.getJSON("../XX/XX/XX/polygons.geojson",function(data){
        polygons = L.geoJSON(data, {
                style:function(feature) {
                switch (feature.properties.color)                     
                },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
               layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);    
    }
        });

 layercontrol.addOverlay(polygons, 'POLYGONS');

 document.getElementById('mapid').style.opacity = 1;

 });
```

I could style the features indivdually like I started in the following script but I dont think it is the most adequate solution since I have more than 100 polygons.

```
/ polygons 
      $.getJSON("../SiteAssets/webparts/Data/WOAs_WGS84.geojson",function    (data){
         woas2 = L.geoJSON(data, {
                        style: function(feature) {
                switch (feature.properties.name) {
                case 'polygon 1: return {color: #00FF7F", opacity:0.7};
                case 'polygon 2:   return {color: "#c917dc", opacity:0.7};
                case 'polygon 3:   return {color: "#FF0000", opacity:0.7};
                case 'polygon 4':   return {color: "#a9fb3a", opacity:0.7};
                case 'polygon 5:   return {color: "#4169E1", opacity:0.7};
```

and so on

```
... 
                case 'polygon 150 ':   return {color: " #C0C0C0", opacity:0.7};     
         },
               onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
               layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);    
         }
         });

            layercontrol.addOverlay(polygons, 'POLYGONS');

               });
```

Comment: Do you want to color the polygons by an attribute or just diffrent colors?

Comment: I am happy to colour them just by different colors, but it would also be good to know how to color them by attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[Leaflet's choropleth example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)  is an excellent place to understand coloring by attributes. 
I didn't change the example much - just followed your sample.

```
// color by attribute.
woas2 = L.geoJSON(data, {
          style: function(feature) {
            d = feature.properties.colorByAttr;
            return d > 1000 ? {color: '#00FF7F', opacity:0.7} :
              d > 500  ? {color: '#BD0026', opacity:0.7} :
              d > 200  ? {color: '#E31A1C', opacity:0.7} :
                         {color: '#FFEDA0', opacity:0.7};     
           },
```

Assigning random colors can also be achieved by creating a function that returns a random color or creating a pre defined array of colors and assigning the colors simillar to your method, though serially instead of 'by name'.