# Setting GeoJSON style based on property value in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

Knowing the thing with leaflet chloropleth:

[Styling individual features in a GeoJSON layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272490/styling-individual-features-in-a-geojson-layer)
https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

we can distinguish the range of values by colour.

I would like to distinguish it by radius.

The example below doesn't explain my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232752/how-to-style-features-depending-on-comparison-operators-in-leaflet

I tried sth like this:

```
 job2 = L.geoJson(data2, {  //layer2 Virgin Media start 
    style: function(feature) {
    if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count > 10)
    return {
    radius: 8
    };
    }
    if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count > 50)
    return {
    radius: 10
    };
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + feature.properties.Address
            label = String(feature.properties.Owner)
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", 
   className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  // Virgin Media tracker data start ---------
                layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
            var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'> 
  <h3>Status:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';                   
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
            layer.on({ 
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': '#663300',
                        'weight':11
                    });
                },
                mouseout: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                        'weight': 2
                    });
                }
            }); //layer.on finish
    } //Virgin Media onEachfeature tracker finish
})//.addTo(map);  //layer 2 Virgin Media finish
```

and also

```
   job2 = L.geoJson(data2, {  //layer2 Virgin Media start   
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + feature.properties.Address
            label = String(feature.properties.Owner)
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  // Virgin Media tracker data start ---------
                layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
            var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'><h3>Status:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';                   
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
            layer.on({ 
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': '#663300',
                        'weight':11
                    });
                },
                mouseout: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                        'weight': 2
                    });
                }
            }); //layer.on finish
    } //Virgin Media onEachfeature tracker finish
})//.addTo(map);  //layer 2 Virgin Media finish

function styling (feature) {
if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count > 20) {
    return {color: "red"}
} else {
    return {color: "yellow"}
}
  }
```

but unfurtunately I can't see the result.

Could we add elements other than equal `===` at all?

[image]

Comment: You will have much greater chances of receiving and answer to your questions if your question is clear and concise: (1) I have this and this (2) On the basis of this and this (data) I want to achieve this (3) I have tried this (4) as a result I get this but not this. I must admit that as your many questions were formulated till now I have hard time understanding what you want to achieve. It should be short and precise.

Comment: So, to continue, your question is probably shortly: I have GeoJSON, where features (point, polygon?) have this property. I would like to display circle markes on each feature with radius that depends on that feature property value. Till now I have tried this, but with no success. I get only this.

Comment: I though, that I clearly precised what I mean. If so, I will work on it.
My thoughs refer to the code
if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count > 10)
    return {
    radius: 8
    };
    }
    if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count > 50)
    return {
    radius: 10
    };
    },
where I want to apply > instead of === but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Basically better is to set the if statements in the return `L.circleMarker` instead of `style`. The statements should be also ordered properly, showing the biggest values on the top and the lowest on the bottom.
Finally the code looks like this:

```
  job2 = L.geoJson(data2, {  //layer2 Virgin Media start    
    style: style2,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            feature.properties.myKey = '<b>'+ feature.properties.Owner + '</b>; ' + 
  feature.properties.Address
            label = String(feature.properties.Owner)
            if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=100)
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:12,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
           else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=50)
           return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:9,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
         }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
            else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count >=1)
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:6,
            opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.8
          }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
            else if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius:4,
            //opacity: .5,
            //color: "#000",
            color:getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillColor:  getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
        }).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, direction: "top", className: "my-labels"}).openTooltip(); 
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  // Virgin Media tracker data start ---------
                layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Owner;
            var popupContent = "<p><h2>" +
                feature.properties.Owner + "</h2><font color='red'><h3>Status:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Status + "</h3><b> NBU ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.NBU + "</br><b> Ticket ID:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Ticket_ID + "</br><b> Address (street):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Address + "</br><b> Address (postcode):</b> " +
                feature.properties.Postcode + "</br><b> Asbestos report:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Asbestos_rep + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Planner</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Planner + "</br><font color='blue'><b>Surveyor</b>:</font> " +
                feature.properties.Surveyor + "</br></h2><b>Units provisional:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Client_Home_Count + "</br></h2><b> Post survey units:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count + "</br> <b>STATS (applied):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_Applied_for_date + "</br> <b>STATS (completed):</b> " +
                feature.properties.STATS_compleeted + "</br> <b>VM issue date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.Date_issued_from_VM + "</br> <b>QC date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date + "</br> <b>VM ECD date:</b> " +
                feature.properties.VM_ECD_date + "</br><b>General notes:</b> " +
                feature.properties.General_notes + "</br>" +
                '</br><center><a href="'+ feature.properties.Directory +'" target="_blank">Local directory</a></center></p>' +
                '<center><font color="red"><a href="'+ feature.properties.Sharepoint +'" target="_blank">Sharepoint</a></font></center></p>';                   
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
                }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
            layer.on({ 
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': '#663300',
                        'weight':11
                    });
                },
                mouseout: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                        'weight': 2
                    });
                }
            }); //layer.on finish
    } 
}).addTo(map);  //layer 2 Virgin Media finish
```

[image]